# xna: several sprites collision treatment

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, monogame

I'm creating a small educatif game using the xna framework (monogame).

I have many sprites in the screen that are moving alone using velocite. I want to add the collision treatment, so when 2 or more sprites intersect they change the direction. but for the moment i haven't resolve it!

This is the update methode of every sprite:

```
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (CollisionDetected())
        {
            Xvelocity = -Xvelocity;
            Yvelocity = -Yvelocity;
        }
        position.X += Xvelocity;
        position.Y += Yvelocity;          
    }

 private bool CollisionDetected()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListCount.Count(); i++)
        {
            if ((this.rectangle().Intersects(ListCount[i].rectangle()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

any tips or ideas on how to do this would be great

Comment: Is `ListCount` a list of all the sprites?

Comment: yes it is, i recuperate it from the spriteManager class whish is static.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing everything in your collision correctly (assuming `ListCount` is a list of all the sprites); however, I don't see anything that is updating the collision rectangles. You are modifying the position of the sprites, but not their collision rectangles. I would try adding this (this assumes that the position refers to the upper-left corner):

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (CollisionDetected())
    {
        Xvelocity = -Xvelocity;
        Yvelocity = -Yvelocity;
    }
    position.X += Xvelocity;
    position.Y += Yvelocity;     
    this.rectangle = new Rectangle(position.X, position.Y, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);     
}
```

This should cause the rectangles to move with the sprites, and then the collisions should work.

Note, if position is referring to the center of the sprite, then use this:

```
this.rectangle = new Rectangle(position.X - rectangle.Width / 2,
   position.Y - rectangle.Height / 2, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
```